# Resetear label al borrar datos en input

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Al introducir un numero identificativo en un input y seleccionar con un selectbutton una opcion aparece una label con el precio que corresponde. Necesito que al borrar el numero identificativo del input desaparezca la label.

[image: formulario]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Por favor agrega el codigo que tienes hasta el momento o lo que has intentado para facilitar la labor de ayuda de lo usuarios. Un saludo:)

Answer (score 0):

si guardas la valor en una variable puedes mostrar dicho valor asi:
{{nombre de tu variable}} 
En tu html pones {{this.variable}} y para actualizar el valor solo tendrias que cambiar el valor de la variable en tu código.

Comment: Puede que tu respuesta solucione su error , pero quedaria mucho mejor si cuando el usuario comparta su codigo pudieras poner un ejemplo algo mas completo :)

Comment: Vale, soy un poco nuevo aquí, lo tendre en cuenta.  :D